# Issues running ray (tune) on an SGE cluster

Tags: python, pytorch, ray, sungridengine, ray-tune

I'm trying to run ray.tune on an SGE cluster to optimise hyperparameters for a model in pytorch. The code runs fine on my laptop (but runs out of memory - hence why I want to use the cluster) but when running on my university cluster I get an error:

```
RuntimeError: Redis has started but no raylets have registered yet.
```

My job script looks like this (sans some header lines related to requesting cluster resources):

```
redis_password="5241590000000000"
port="6379"

#store stdout from ray in variable
ray_output=$(ray start --head --port $port --redis-password=$redis_password)

#get line number of IP address
ip_line=$(printf '%q\n' $ray_output | grep -n "IP:" | cut -d : -f 1)
ip_line=$((ip_line+1))

#get the IP address
ip=$(printf '%q\n' $ray_output | sed -n $ip_line'p')
ray_address=$ip":"$port

#execute the python script, passing ray address
python synthetic_geno_nn_cls.py $trainfile $testfile $ray_address $redis_password
```

And my python code initialises ray with the following:

```
#receive command line inputs
train_f = sys.argv[1]
test_f = sys.argv[2]
ray_address = sys.argv[3]
redis_password = sys.argv[4]

#initialise ray
ray.init(address=ray_address, _redis_password=redis_password)
```

I've also tried this without specifying the address/redis password and using address='auto', but that gave the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!